# LDAP Query for fetching dn and all cn data

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query

[image]

I'm using netscape ldapsdk-4.1.jar,I am able to connect & authenticate with my ldap server :

```
try{
            ldi.connect(hostname,LDAPv3.DEFAULT_PORT);
            LDAPConnectionInfo.ldapSearchResults = ldi.search(LDAPConnectionInfo.MY_SEARCHBASE,LDAPConnectionInfo.MY_SCOPE,LDAPConnectionInfo.MY_FILTER,null,false);
            System.out.println("Ldap Search Result : " +LDAPConnectionInfo.ldapSearchResults);
            
            ldi.authenticate(3, "host", "****");
}
.....
```

Now I want fetch the data from :

- Under the domain component(dn, here=example.com) how many organizational units(ou) are there.
- For each organizational unit(ou) to get all common name(cn) and it's  leaf objects under the common name(cn).

I think I have to use some ldap query to fetch these data....any input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can share some code?

Comment: to be frank,I'm able to connect and authenticate with the server and that part (in terms of code is very simple)...but I'm trying accessing the all data under each cn,to me that part is challenging...can you share any idea.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ldapsdk, but you have to create the correct LDAP queries to get the data. Some examples are available here: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: @home thanks,though I have gone through this link ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a search request for each organizational unit where:

- the base object is the organizational unit
- the scope is `subtree`
- the filter is either `objectClass=commonObjectClass` where `commonObjectCLass` is an objectClass common to entries to be retrieved, or `cn=*`
- the list of attributes to be retrieved for each entry

transmit each search request in turn to the LDAP directory server and interpret the responses.

*Do not use the netscape code, it's ancient, buggy, and slow. Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) instead*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can provide me some links for fair understanding related to accessing cn

Comment: See the links in the 'About' section [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/810802/terry-gardner)

Comment: Is there any local LDAP server on the development machine (using: Windows 7 Pro) for our application(testing purpose)?